# when i signal something like '01%' i don't get a warning

Tags: mysql

After this trigger i dont get a warning if i inserted 5 in foo.x

```
\d $
CREATE TRIGGER `tri` BEFORE INSERT ON `foo` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.bar = 5 THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '01002' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'MSG';
    END IF;
END$\d ;

INSERT INTO `foo` values (5);
```

> 1 row affected

Comment: Could you show us table schema?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As documented under [Changes in MySQL 5.5.8 (2010-12-03, General Availability)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/news-5-5-8.html):

> #### Bugs Fixed
>
> `[ deletia ]`
>
> - Warnings raised by a trigger were not cleared upon successful completion. Now warnings are cleared if the trigger completes successfully, per the SQL standard. ([Bug #55850](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=55850))

Comment: this is not the bug i am talking about in this tri trigger i am having a user defined sqlstate not the one  we talked about

Comment: @eggyal +1. Did not know it.

Comment: @RamiJamleh: You are using a `SQLSTATE` commencing `01`, which is a *warning*; as such, since MySQL version 5.5.8, such warnings are discarded on successful execution of the trigger.

Comment: @RamiJamleh: As explained above, it's not a bug.  It's by design.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that trigger was created? I have got two errors.

Try to use this statement instead -

```
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '01002' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'MSG';
```

- '010002' -> '01002'
- TEXT_MESSAGE -> MESSAGE_TEXT

[SIGNAL Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html).

Comment: The OP edited the question and fixed these two issues so I guess (just a guess) it was a typo when posting here. I've tried it myself and the corrected code does not indeed trigger a warning (MySQL/5.5.28).

Comment: Have a look at eggyal's answer. It answers the question.